# Graphie du mot otage

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, histoire, écriture

Ce mot vient de l'ancien français *[hostage](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/otage/56803)*. Pourquoi la disparition de s n'a pas entraîné l'apparition d'un o avec un accent circonflexe (comme par exemple pour hôtel, hôpital, [etc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otage#%C3%89tymologie).) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Extrait:**

> Système complexe, que le circonflexe des réformateurs a unifié, mais
>   en oubliant certains termes au passage : aile, chaque, bouchon,cette,
>   Etat, flacon, otage .....  Ainsi, il n'est pas exact de dire que
>   l'accent circonflexe remplace un s disparu.

**Source** : https://www.persee.fr/doc/mots_0243-6450_1991_num_28_1_2039 page 105

Comment: L'article de Tournier cite N. Catach pour l'affirmation « il n'est pas exact... ». Merci !